# TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable using REQUESTS module in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to python and new to 'requests' module, and stackoverflow so go easy on me. :)
If anyone can give me some pointers on what this means in reference to my code, I'd be deeply grateful.

Code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://somewebsite.com/svc/api/json/loginUser'


headers = {'User-Agent':'Python _dopost() method',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset':'Shift_JIS,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate',
    'Content-Type':'/plain; charset=UTF-8'}

data = {'<soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body><loginUser><email>tacoflavoredkisses@yum.com</email><password>password</password><setcookie>1</setcookie><remember>1</remember></loginUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Error: TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

with a very long python error, heres a snippet, hopefully enough.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
176             else:
177                 filename = fname
--> 178             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

 21 
 22 payload = {'<soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body><loginUser><email>tacoflavoredkisses@yum.com</email><password>password</password><setcookie>1</setcookie><remember>1</remember></loginUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'}
---> 23 r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
 24 
 25 print r.status_code

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.pyc in post(url, data, **kwargs)
 85     """
 86 
---> 87     return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.pyc in request(method, url, **kwargs)
 42 
 43     session = sessions.Session()
---> 44     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert)
277 
278         # Send the request.
--> 279         resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
372         """Send a given PreparedRequest."""
373         adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
--> 374         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The `data` argument to `requests.post` must be either a dictionary, bytes, or a file-like object. You are passing in a set. This is the reason you are getting the `TypeError`. Look at some of [these](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) examples for more help.

Comment: changing data to a str worked. Its crazy how hard the simple things are when a newbie. Both of you were right, thank you! anything I need to do? not sure i can select best answer with such low rank. Wish I could pay it forward.

Comment: Glad it worked. Nothing need be done. If you want you can [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) so others can learn from it and know that the question was answered. Otherwise, just have fun with Python and help others if you can. :)

Answer (score 2):

Changing data to be a string resolved this issue for me.